# Laravel Delete function not work

Tags: php, laravel

First project on laravel :  When I am going to delete row it throws an Error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails.
My controller function

```
 public function delete(Request $request) {
    try {
        Venue::findOrFail($request->id)->delete();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response()->json([
                'error' => $ex->getCode(),
                'message' => $ex->getMessage()
            ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
            'message' => trans('admin.venue.delete_success')
        ]);
}
```

Model  :

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::deleting(function (Venue $venue) {
        $venue->occasions()->delete();
        $venue->contact()->delete();
        $venue->gallery()->delete(); // here i am gtng error
        $venue->venueParameter()->delete();
    });
}
```

Error in detail :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`red_carpet`.`media`, CONSTRAINT `media_gallery_id_foreign` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`gallery_id`) REFERENCES `galleries` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from
>   `galleries` where `galleries`.`source_id` = 2 and
>   `galleries`.`source_id` is not null and `galleries`.`source_type` =
>   App\Venue)

Schema of table :

```
Schema::create('venues', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('client_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('logo');
        $table->unsignedInteger('venue_type_id');
        $table->boolean('is_premium');
        $table->boolean('is_verified');
        $table->string('tripadvisor_url')->nullable();
        $table->enum('status',['Active','Inactive']);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
        $table->foreign('venue_type_id')->references('id')->on('venue_types');
    });

  Schema::create('galleries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('source_type');
        $table->unsignedInteger('source_id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->unsignedInteger('sort_order');
        $table->enum('status',['Active','Inactive']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('gallery_id');
        $table->enum('type',['Image','Video']);
        $table->string('caption');
        $table->string('path')->nullable();
        $table->string('thumbnail')->nullable();
        $table->longText('video_code')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_banner_image')->default(false);
        $table->boolean('is_thumb_image')->default(false);
        $table->unsignedInteger('sort_order');
        $table->enum('status',['Active','Inactive']);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('gallery_id')->references('id')->on('galleries');
    });
```

Comment: you cannot delete parent row as it violates foreign key constraint. you should use `->onDelete('cascade');` where you have defined your foreign key

Comment: can't delete gallery because media has records pointing to those keys

Comment: Where i can add cascade as i do not know about more.

Comment: Can you show shema of all tables involved in the error?

Comment: you want to see table structure ?

Comment: @programmingArrow added

Comment: Seriously, deleting rows is a big no. Use `SoftDelete`

Comment: @PaulSantos help me to implement this.

Answer (score 5):

If you are deleting items from one table that are linked with the other table, then it gives you this error.

If you are using a pivot table, then use onDelete('cascade') like,

```
$table->foreign('foreign_key')->references('primary_key')->on('table_name')->onDelete('cascade');
```

[Ref](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema):

Comment: Inside your schema config

Comment: I confirm. This works. Just make sure you add ->onDelete('cascade'); on all related tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
  onDelete('cascade')
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, you can use `onDelete` method to prevent the error. But I dont recommend to actually `delete` your records in the database.

You can use `SoftDeletes` to delete records by adding a `deleted_at` timestamp field to your table schema. Then all your queries will only fetch rows where `deleted_at IS null`

To enable this in your models, make sure that your tables has `$table->softDeletes()`. This will add the necessary `deleted_at` field to your tables.

Next, add the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` trait to your models like this.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes; 

class Foo extends Model { 
    use SoftDeletes; 
}
```

Aaannd, that's it! Every time you perform a query with `Foo`, all `non-null` deleted_at value will be ignored.

```
$foos = Foo::all();
```

And whenever you perform `delete()`, it will simply update `deleted_at` to the current timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

In your table, For example:

```
$table->foreign('user_id') ->references('id')->on('users') ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your gallery migration file inside `database/migrations/examplegallerytable.php` and update the relationship definition to these:

```
$table->foreign('media_id')->references('id')->on('medias')->onDelete('cascade');
```

then run these command:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

and

```
php artisan migrate
```

that's all

Comment: So i just replace  Schema of media table last line  $table->foreign('gallery_id')->references('id')->on('galleries'); ?? replace with this ?@ERSS

Comment: no replace instead the Schema of the child table (galleries) with the code above and give me feedbacks @dashinglove143

Comment: On galleries schema i just added  ` $table->foreign('source_id')->references('id')->on('venues')->onDelete('cascade');` throw same error @ERSS your answer is correct but am nt gtng it.

Comment: @dashinglove143 am not understanding your last comment, please explain well

Comment: @dashinglove143 if my answer is correct then you should accept it

Comment: just added in migrations file create_galleries_table.php above code but not working..